# Prolog: How to get a path from a start node to a Goal Node

Tags: search, prolog, artificial-intelligence, nodes, predicate

I'm trying to write a prolog program that will represent a goal node **G** and will return a list of nodes from a predicate called something like `get_path(StartNode, Path)` from the start node to the goal node.

I have a set of nodes, each with a heuristic value, some successor arcs to travel from one node to another, and a cost for doing so. The heuristic values for each are:

```
h(a,12).
h(b,8).
h(c,4).
h(d,3).
h(f,5).
h(e,5).
h(g,0).
```

And the successor arcs and associated costs are:

```
s(a,b,3).
s(a,c,6).
s(b,d,4).
s(b,e,2).
s(d,e,2).
s(d,g,1).
s(e,g,3).
s(c,e,5).
s(c,f,4).
s(f,g,7).
```

I have [drawn out a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztn2.jpg) that maps all the node routes I can take, and as such I know that both `a->b->e->g` and `a->b->d->g`is the cheapest paths I can follow, each with a total cost of 8.
However I'm just not entirely sure what kind of predicate I should write that will take in this information as well as output my results needed. 
Do I use breadth first search? 
And where does the Heuristic value come into play with the solution?

Any help at all would be majorly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: With "draw out a chart" do you mean that the *prolog predicate* should generate an image?

Comment: Since you didn't show any attempt at code, it's hard to tell how much Prolog you know. First, you need to decide how you want to represent a path, normally a list. Next, write down recursive rules (in whatever form you like - just in plain language for example) with appropriate termination condition. Then translate your rule to Prolog. For example, *[A|T] is a path from S to E if there is an arc A from S to X, and T is a path from X to E*. You can include rules for costs and such as needed. Once you have the basics down, then you can go back and determine how you want to obtain cheapest cost.

Comment: Is the graph directed? Or can the arc `s(a,b,3)` be traversed in both directions? And what heuristic are the _heuristic values_ for the nodes supposed to represent?

Comment: @tas: Yes, the graph is directed! One-way only. The heuristic is the estimate of the distance from node **_n_** to goal node **g**. Apologies, I should have clarified.

Comment: @lurker: I would say my knowledge of Prolog is still in the beginner level. I'm taking a course on it currently and unfortunately the notes I'm given from the lecturer don't do a great amount towards explaining the language.
Could you further explain your example above about how `[A|T] is a path from S to E if there is an arc A from S to X, and T is a path from X to E`? Thank you kindly.

Comment: If you think of the path as a list and each element of the list represents an arc along the way, then `[A|T]` is a path from node `S` to node `E` if the first element of that list (`A`) is an arc from `S` to some other node `X`, and the rest of the list `T` is a path from node `X` to node `E`. That should be fairly intuitive. That can be expressed in Prolog as, `path(S, E, [A|T]) :- s(S, X, _), path(X, E, T).` and the trivial or base case is `path(S, E, [S-E]) :- s(S, E, _).` (I chose the term `X-Y` to represent an arc in the list, but you can choose your representation to suit your needs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a framework for traversing the graph which, hopefully, you can expand upon to utilize the associated costs. This is very common solution in Prolog. This will answer directly the subject question, "How to get a path from a start node to a Goal Node".

The form of the query would be: `path(Start, Destination, Path)`. I need a starting and a destination to determine a specific path, so the suggestion of `get_path(StartNode, Path)` isn't sufficient since it doesn't indicate an end point. If you wish to keep the end point variable, you can query, for example, `path(a, Destination, Path)` and it will provide solutions for a variety of specific `Destination` instantiations.

The approach will include a new auxiliary variable to keep track of visited nodes. This is to avoid loops. This will also assume a directed graph (a point not clarified in the original question), so that if I have the arc `s(a,b,3)`, then there's a path from `a` to `b` with a cost of `3`, but it does not mean that there's a path from `b` to `a`.

```
path(Start, Destination, Path) :-
    path(Start, Destination, [], Path).

path(Start, Start, _, [Start]).   % I'm already where I want to be
path(Start, Destination, Visited, [Start|Nodes]) :-
    \+ member(Start, Visited),
    dif(Start, Destination),
    s(Start, Node, _),       % Ignoring cost
    path(Node, Destination, [Start|Visited], Nodes).
```

So you can query as follows, for example, to find paths from `a` to `g`:

```
| ?- path(a, g, Path).

Path = [a,b,d,e,g] ? ;

Path = [a,b,d,g] ? ;

Path = [a,b,e,g] ? ;

Path = [a,c,e,g] ? ;

Path = [a,c,f,g] ? ;

(15 ms) no
| ?-
```

You can also try a more general query:

```
| ?- path(a, D, P).

D = a
P = [a] ? ;

D = b
P = [a,b] ? ;

D = d
P = [a,b,d] ? ;
...
```

If you want to look at the cost of a node, you would consider, `h(Node, Cost)`. You can include an argument to include the total cost of the path (however you wish to compute it) and accumulate it with each recursion through the `path` predicate call.

I know in my comments to the original question, I said that you could use a list of arcs to describe the path, which one could, but in this case, I chose nodes. They're isomorphic.

This should give you a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified but For the purpose of this program, G is the only Goal node. Is there any major changes I should make to the code structure to support this rule?

Comment: @StephenDunne that doesn't impact the approach I provided. My answer describes a common pattern for traversing a graph. You might have to do some tweaks to meet your requirements. If you already have a specific goal node, `G`, you just provide it as an argument just as I show in the first query example in which I provided `g` as a specific goal and the program showed all of the possible paths to `g` from `a`. I can also leave the first argument open to find all paths to `g` from anywhere: `path(Start, g, Path).`.

Comment: ts just that the question im dealt with requires my predicate that i query to be: get_path (StartNode,Path). It cant have a 3rd variable such as destination. I think i may have solved it though.

Comment: Can you See my attempt below?

Answer (score 1):

I think i may have solved it thanks to @lurkers help.

```
goal (g).
get_path (StartNode,Path) :- path (Start,g,[],Path).

path (Start,Start,_,[Start]).

path (Start,g,Visited,[Start|Nodes]):-
  \+member (Start,Visited),
 dif (Start, g),
 s(Start, Node,_),
 path (Node,g,[Start|Visited],Nodes).
```

Comment: You can use `maplist(dif(Start), Visited)` to increase the generality of your relation!

Comment: @mat How do you mean?

Comment: I mean instead of using `(\+)/1` you can use the predicates `dif/2` and `maplist/2` to express that `Start` does *not* occur in the list `Visited`. This is more general and can be used in all directions. For example, try: `?- maplist(dif(X), Ls).`. In contrast, `\+ member(X, Ls)` simply *fails* and hence cannot be used to *generate* solutions. It is good practice to keep your predicates as general as you can, so that you can ideally use them in all directions.

Comment: I don't understand. You initially accepted my answer, then used it, nearly verbatim, to write your own answer, and then rescinded your acceptance of my answer? That seems a bit irregular. Also, the answer you're providing has some issues. What's the purpose of the fact `goal(g).`? Fixing g in the code seems restrictive when you can simply call `path(Start, g, Path)` using the answer I already provided. So `get_path(Start, Path) :- path(Start, g, Path).` I would think.

Comment: @lurker Apologies. I unaccepted it by accident. I posed my attempt as an answer for formatting reasons and then accepted it thinking it was yours! As for my answer, you can see I changed your line `path(Start, Destination, Path) :-
    path(Start, Destination, [], Path).` to `get_path (StartNode,Path) :- path (Start,g,[],Path).`as I was asking to see if that would work in its place. My assigned task requires this line: `get_path (StartNode,Path)` which is why I made the change. Querying if that would still work.

Comment: @StephenDunne no worries. As I mentioned in my comment, you can just do `get_path(Start, Path) :- path(Start, g, Path).` leaving the generic `path/3` concept intact, or do what you suggested that bypasses `path/3` and goes right to `path/4`. The `goal(g).` fact you posted doesn't serve a purpose in the code, however.